# How to write batch file in SAS that automates the opening of files?

Tags: sas

I was assigned a task that I don’t know where to start. Here’s the context:

There’s a variable in the data, say VAR1, indicating the directory to a bunch of image files. So for observation 1, VAR1 may look like D:\Project\Data\Images\Image1.tiff and so on. Of course, those image files exist in the computer.

What I need to do is to figure out SAS program(s) and later run them automatically using batch file. When the batch file runs, it will, in some way, opens the image files one by one. By “one by one”, I mean it firsts open one image file and, upon closing that file, it opens the next image file until the end of the list.

Better yet, the batch file will make a copy of the original image files and put them in some folder (e.g., D:\Project\Data\Temp images) before opening them. That is to make sure original data is left untouched.

Do you know how I can write such a program in SAS? I was given the following SPSS file for reference, which does that job nicely as described. I don’t know enough SPSS to understand every detail how it works. The two variables dir5 and tiff5 specify the location of the image files, and variables SCQID and ohhscqid are just ID variables.

```
    string out2 (a200).

    compute out2=concat('copy "', ltrim(rtrim(dir5)),"\", tiff5, '"',' "c:\temp\temp.tiff"').

    write outfile='E:\Data\Outcome.bat'/'@echo SCQ ID  ' ohhscqid .

    write outfile='E:\Data\Outcome.bat'/out2.

    write outfile='E:\Data\Outcome.bat'/'@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OIS.exe" "c:\temp\temp.tiff"'.

execute.
```

I did the homework and figured out one way that works as I want it to. Not the optimal way programmingly though, but the idea is like this.

```
data batwide;set have;
echo = '@echo SCQ ID '||ohhscqid;
predir = 'copy '||'"'||strip(dir5)||strip('\')||strip(tiff5)||strip('"');
preexec = '@'||strip('"')||strip('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OIS.exe')||strip('"');
temp = '"'||strip('c:\temp\temp.tiff')||strip('"');
run;

data batwide; set batwide;
dir = catx(' ',predir,temp);
exec = catx(' ',preexec,temp);
run;

data batlong;set batwide;
format bat $200.;
bat = echo;output;
bat = dir;output;
bat = exec;output;
keep bat;
run;

data _null_;
set batlong;
file "E:\SAS codes and files\batchfile.bat";
put bat;
run;
```

Comment: This is not SAS base code. Please tell us what it is. Probably you forgot a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking how to generate a series of OS commands into a text file?  You can use a DATA step for that.

If you want to test if the specified files exist then use the `FILEEXIST()` function.

So if you have SAS dataset name `HAVE` with a variable named `VAR1` that contains the filename then you probably want a program like this:

```
data _null_;
  set have ;
  file 'E:\Data\Outcome.bat';
  if fileexist(VAR1) then do;
    target=catx('\','D:\Project\Data\Temp images',scan(VAR1,-1,'\'));
    put 'copy ' VAR1 :$quote. target :$quote. ;
    put '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OIS.exe" ' target :$quote.;
  end;
  else putlog 'WARNING: File not found. ' VAR1=;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution looks more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SPSS, but will give you an example using unix commands, you can change them to Windows commands and probably do what you described.
In this example I'll only copy some files, but the logic to "open the files one by one" is the same. You will have to play with the code and adjust it to Windows.

First of all, we looking for csv files inside the /home/user directory. Again, adjust the command to windows.
This will create a sas dataset with all the files

```
filename dirlist pipe "find /home/user/ | grep csv";

data dirlist ;                                               
infile dirlist lrecl=200 truncover;                          
input line $200.;  
file_name = strip(line); 
keep file_name;
run;
```

Then I'll create a macro variable with the file count, I'll all it cntfiles

```
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into: cntfiles from dirlist;
quit;
%let cntfiles=&cntfiles;
%put cntfiles=&cntfiles;
```

The last thing I'm doing is, I'm looping, getting the filenames one by one and copying them to a new macro variable called &copyto
This data step (*null*) will only copy the files, if you want to do something else with them, you'll have to write the code for it.

```
%macro process_files;
%let copyto = /home/des/33889897/copyto;
%do i=1 %to &cntfiles;

data _null_;
    set dirlist (firstobs=&i.);
    put file_name=;
    call system("cp -f " || file_name || " &copyto");
    stop;
run;

%end;
%mend process_files;
%process_files;
```

Take a look at this [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#exittemp.htm), maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

sample code I use frequently to parse list of files in a directory and extract metadata from the file names. Often feeds a step to generate a sequence of macro variables to use in a macro loop to process each file in turn.  Just add any substringing of filenames to extract structured content as with the datetxt and date assigment statements in the example where the filename has a datestamp in it that I want to use.

```
%let extension=txt;
filename infiles "c:\a\b\c";

Data List_of_files
     Not_ext
     ;
Length
 path $255
 filename $255
 extension $10
;
 d_open=dopen("infiles") ;
 path=pathname("infiles") ;
 nfiles=dnum(d_open) ;
 do i=1 to nfiles;
                 filename =dread(d_open,i) ;
                 extension=scan(filename,-1,'.') ;
                 datetxt=scan(filename,2,"_");
                 date=input(scan(filename,2,"_"),date9.);
                 if upcase(extension) ne "%upcase(&extension)"
                    then output Not_ext ;
                    else output list_of_files ;
                 end;
 d_open=dclose(d_open) ;
keep
 filename
 path
 extension
;
Run ;
filename infiles clear;
```